# i want task detail along with it's feature id and comments by one query in vsts

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

i want last five minutes modified task with following detail by one query 
i am using wiql library

following query i am using currently 
and its give me last modified task , then after i need to call another api to find feature detail of its task

```
 Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
                {
                    Query = "Select [System.Id], " +
                        "[System.Title], " +
                        "[System.State] " +
                        "From WorkItems Where " +
                        "[System.WorkItemType] =" +
                        "'Task' AND [System.ChangedDate] >= '" + fromTime + "' AND [System.ChangedDate] <= '" + ToTime + "'  " +
                        "order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
                };
                //create instance of work item tracking http client
                using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
                {
                    //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
                    WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult;
                    workItemQueryResult = await workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql);
```

can some one suggests how to find out task and its feature detail by one query

Answer (score 0):

If you say about hierarchy Feture->Task, you can try the tree query type. As example:

```
SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItemLinks 
WHERE ([Source].[System.TeamProject] = '<TEAM_PROJECT_NAME>'  AND  [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature') And 
([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') And ([Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' 
AND  [Target].[System.ChangedDate] > START_DATE 
AND  [Target].[System.ChangedDate] < END_DATE) ORDER BY [System.Id] 
mode(Recursive,ReturnMatchingChildren)
```

The result will be available in WorkItemRelations property of WorkItemQueryResult class. Each relation contains Source and Target. If Source is null, a work item id in Target is a first item on the tree.

Comment: thanks , its give me task and its feature id , that is perfect but if i want detail of task with in same query what can i do i mean comments,task title  etc

Comment: @vaibhavpancholi yes, that`s constraint of the query with links. you should use GetWorkItemAsync to get work item details.